# How is there fewer zeros in the left of 1 in this language?

Tags: context-free-grammar, palindrome

From Hopcroft's Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computations, 3ed, chapter 5 p. 172:

[image: pal]

I don't quite get how can there be fewer 0's in the left of `1` if we have `w = 0^n*1*0^n`?

Comment: $w=xyz$ has equally many zeros in the left and right groups, so when you form $xz$ by deleting $y$, you've deleted some of the left zeros (because that's what $y$ consists of), leaving fewer zeros on the left than on the right.

Comment: Thank you @AndreasBlass.  They should have said there is no zero in the left instead.

Comment: No, there could still be some zeros on the left; $y$ "consists of one or more $0$'s from the first group", not necessarily all of the $0$'s from the first group. (You should probably review the statement of the pumping lemma to check how much one can assume about the deleted segment $y$.)

Comment: Thanks again for the insight.